# Why are the numbers I input only read to 6 significant figures?

Tags: c++, double, decimal, precision

I am trying to run the following program and it works but when I enter a value that is more than 6 decimal places it keeps getting rounded/truncated e.g. 2.999999 --> 3. How do I set it so it stops doing this?

```
int main()
{

    double n=0, x=0; 

    while (cin >> n >> x) //will keep going until an integer is not entered
    {
       cout << "You entered the two integers " << x << " and " << n << endl;

       if (x-n <= (1.0/10000000) && n-x <= (1.0/10000000)) 
          cout << "The numbers are almost equal" << endl;
    }

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's rounding/truncating on input, or is it happening on output instead? IIRC, `cout`'s standard formatting for doubles defaults to 6 significant places or so, unless you set the appropriate flags to tell it otherwise...

Comment: yeh it is happening on the output...

Comment: Two suggestions. First, the comments and text refer to "integer", but the values have type double; this should probably be fixed. Second, the test can be made simpler if it uses `abs(x - n);` so that there's only one test needed.

Comment: Yeh sorry bout that I was cutting and changing code guess I forgot to change the text and comments XD. Thanks for the abs tip...I only just started learning and I am going through stroustrup's book and I haven't come across that yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change precision of the values that you print by using [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision):

```
cout << "You entered the two integers " << setprecision(20) << x
     << " and " << n << endl;
```

[Link to ideone.](http://ideone.com/HurBv)

Comment: Is there no way to set the precision prior to the cout statement i.e. at the start where I declare n and x?

Comment: @user1542646 Absolutely - you are free to move the `cout << setprecision(20);` to any part of your program. The precision will remain in effect until you set a different value to it.

Comment: Wow yeah sorry total newb on this site!!